# How do I resize the colorbar to my bar graph?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, matplotlib, colormap

I know this question has been asked quite a lot of times, but this one is simply driving me nuts. I couldn't resize the colorbar according to the chart. 
Here is a code I tried to implement.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
import numpy as np
%matplotlib notebook
t = df.size
STD = df.std(axis=0)/np.sqrt(t)
df = pd.DataFrame([np.random.normal(32000,200000,3650), 
                   np.random.normal(43000,100000,3650), 
                   np.random.normal(43500,140000,3650), 
                   np.random.normal(48000,70000,3650)], 
                  index=[1992,1993,1994,1995])
colors = cm.hsv(df / float(max(df)))
plt.clf()
plt.colorbar(plot)
plt.bar(df.index,df.mean(axis=1),yerr = t,color=colors[0])
plt.show()
help(cm.hsv)
```

And apart from this question, how did you learn matplotlib and its classes/methods to manipulate the graph? Was it simply by practice/searching through documentation or did you learn this library by going through courses/videos/books?

Comment: The provided code doesn't make much sense. A colorbar is called before anything is drawn, `STD` is calculated from an undefined `df`, the bar plot only contains one color (not very interesting for a colorbar), ...   A default colorbar gets the same size as the axis to which it belongs. What exactly do you want to achieve???

Comment: Im completely confused myself. I want error bars of length standard error of mean on each 'bar'. and I want a colorbar beside it having colors to map values bar graph values from 0 to 60k. Please help me.

Comment: You might want to check out seaborn's [barplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html).

Comment: I browsed and experimented on seaborn. Seaborn is much smoother,easier to handle and more visually appealing. I don't know if my instructor would allow the use of seaborn in my assignment, but only one way to find out.